# Jest: Connect to the mongoose before testing begins

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I start the server as a separate process, after which I run the tests on the Jest like this:

```
beforeAll(function (done) {
    server = fork('server/start_server.js');
    exec('node ../utility/new_user.js User Pass testing');
    setTimeout(() => {
        done();
    }, 2000);
});

afterAll(function () {
    fork('server/clean_db.js');
    server.kill();
});

test('Login', () => {
    login().then((data) => {
        expect(data.logged).toBeTruthy();
    })
});
```

The "start_server.js" file starts the http server and connects to the database (MongoDB through Mongoose). But the problem is that when the "Login" test send the request an error is returned - `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080`. I assume that this is because the application does not have time to connect to the database. How to fix it without carrying out the database connection in the test file?